# Jblas, Error on argument 8 (LDA) in DGEMM

Tags: java, matrix, blas

I am calculating a covariance matrix without any problems like so:

```
    DoubleMatrix W = new DoubleMatrix(w);
    DoubleMatrix ret = new DoubleMatrix(coReturns);
    DoubleMatrix meanRets = ret.columnMeans();
    DoubleMatrix demeanedReturns = ret.subRowVector(meanRets);
    DoubleMatrix S = demeanedReturns.transpose().mmul(demeanedReturns).div(varianceDataPoints - 1);
```

But suddenly I get this Exception thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: XERBLA: Error on argument 8 (LDA) in DGEMM
    at org.jblas.NativeBlas.dgemm(Native Method)
    at org.jblas.SimpleBlas.gemm(SimpleBlas.java:247)
    at org.jblas.DoubleMatrix.mmuli(DoubleMatrix.java:1781)
    at org.jblas.DoubleMatrix.mmul(DoubleMatrix.java:3138)
```

I really have no idea what this exception is trying to tell me. And google does not know either. Can someone explain me what is going on here and how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the purpose of LDA [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d2b/dgemm_8f.html):

```
 LDA is INTEGER
           On entry, LDA specifies the first dimension of A as declared
           in the calling (sub) program. When  TRANSA = 'N' or 'n' then
           LDA must be at least  max( 1, m ), otherwise  LDA must be at
           least  max( 1, k ).
```

There is a related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206563/purpose-of-lda-argument-in-blas-dgemm) which explains its meaning.

The source code for jblas is [here](https://github.com/mikiobraun/jblas) so you should be able to step through it and figure out what is going on. 
Seems odd that on the line you get the exception (`SimpleNative:247`), LDA is set to 0 (as opposed to a value between 1 and k). I would recommend to open an issue on the [jblas issue tracker](https://github.com/mikiobraun/jblas/issues).